# Identify process that is creating a file

Tags: file, process, filesystemwatcher, identify

I sometimes get a file called tmp#####.tmp.bat in my user/appdata/local/temp folder
I am suspecting its created by some Cannon printter utilities
I thought I would put a FileSystemWatcher on the folder and  catch the creator in the act
I can catch the creation of the file, but how do I identify the process creating it?
Any ideas? I would like to log the creation and the process name creating it.

Answer (score -1):

Ive found the .tmp.bat is part of a package called ITSupport247
I dont know how it got onto my box, but I suspect it was silently installed along with other software updates.

I found it by running ProcessMonitor, filtering for path contains .tmp.bat, and just letting it run until I started getting some events.

Should have thought of ProcessMonitor right away.